# How do introduce DBF files into a XAMPP workspace

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp, dbf

So I'm a little new to PHP and databases. I have a few questions about them.

I have a POS that saves its databases with the DBF extension. I can access them and edit them with Microsoft Access 2007.

Meanwhile, I have just installed XAMPP. I would like to incorporate already existing Databases from my POS for our website. However I can't find any DBF files in the XAMMP folder, so I'm wondering:

**When you create a database through phpMyAdmin, how is it stored in the filing system if not a DBF file?**

Answer (score 1):

The answer is the "My" part of phpMyAdmin - MySQL. DBF is an ancient & beloved format, which I have used in various systems for over 30 years, starting with dBase II. I am currently working on moving one of my last 2 functioning DBF-based systems to MySQL & PHP. MySQL has its own on-disk format - .frm, .ibd, .MYD, MYI, etc. The important thing is that the details are normally hidden from the user & from the programmer. You actually only need to deal with the files directly under relatively unusual circumstances - e.g., I have migrated large MySQL databases between systems by copying the files, but that is not normally recommended for a variety of reasons.

There are tools available to export data from DBF files into MySQL. I have used one quite a bit (I can't remember the name and my understanding is that software recommendations are not usually a great idea on Stackoverflow) but there are several and they can save a lot of work in the transition by creating tables matching the original structure. When I have done that, all I needed to do afterwards was add some decent indexes and (if I didn't have already) unique ID index fields, and everything works quite well.

Is it possible to access DBF files directly in PHP? Probably, but I wouldn't recommend it.